# Maps between colimit objects

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ and $\lbrace B_j \rbrace_{j\in J}$ be two diagrams in a category $\mathcal{C}$. Let $A=\text{colim}_{i\in I} A_i$ and $B= \text{colim}_{j\in J} B_j$. Given two maps $f,g: A\rightarrow B$, assuming that the coequaliser $C$ exists, can $C$ be presented in terms of the colimit of a diagram that consists of objects $A_i$ and $B_j$?

Comment: Is there any relation between $I$ and $J$?

Comment: If you regard $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ as diagrams in $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ and are able to lift $f, g : A \to B$ to $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$, then yes, there is a diagram constructed from $A$ and $B$ whose colimit is $C$.

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin, I suppose you're talking about Yoneda embedding. Why do we need to consider that though?

Comment: It is the free colimit-completion of $\mathcal{C}$, so _very_ roughly speaking anything you can prove about colimits there will also be true in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Hi @AnginaSeng, what if no further assumption is given?

Comment: @ZhenLin, I mean if $C$ is the colimit of a diagram consisting of $A_i$ and $B_j$ in the functor category, then $C$ (its existence in $\mathcal{C}$ is assumed) is the colimit of the same diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. So I don't see why we need to consider the free cocompletion.. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Why does this question have two votes to close? It's a fine question.

Answer (score 5):

It's a tempting but false conjecture! Let all the $A_i$ and $B_i$ be copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the category $\text{Ab}$ of abelian groups and let both of the colimits be coproducts. Then every abelian group occurs as a coequalizer of a pair of maps between such coproducts (this says exactly that every abelian group has a presentation) but *not* every abelian group occurs as a colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. I asked exactly this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z) awhile ago and got a very informative negative answer.

Comment: I see.  I was actually thinking about a related question: If we have embeddings of  categories $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}$, then does $\mathcal{A}$ being dense in $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ being dense in $\mathcal{C}$ imply $\mathcal{A}$ being dense in $\mathcal{C}$? It seems the answer should be negative, right?

Comment: @Parkey: I have heard that this is false. Tom Leinster claims it in these slides but doesn't provide an explicit counterexample: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/ucr/ucr_talk.pdf

Comment: Doesn't your example provide a counterexample? Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the subcategory of $Ab$ which contains the single object $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{B}$ be the subcategory of $Ab$ containing objects that be presented as the colimit of some copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{C}=Ab$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that sounds right. Or at least, I definitely believe that $B$ is dense in $C$ since it contains all the free abelian groups, and I find it plausible but haven't carefully checked that $A$ is dense in $B$.

Comment: Doesn't $\mathcal{A}$ being dense in $\mathcal{B}$ simply mean every object in $\mathcal{B}$ can be expressed as the colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{B}$ by definition? Did I miss something here?

Comment: @Parkey: that's one possible notion of density but I think it's not the standard one. Density means that every object in $B$ is *canonically* the colimit of objects in $A$, meaning that associated to every $b \in B$ there's a distinguished diagram of objects in $A$ and we want that specific diagram to exhibit $b$ as a colimit. See Tom Leinster here on "dense" vs. "colimit-dense" after Definition 3.6: http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/generators.pdf

Comment: Actually Tom's remark there should imply that $A$ isn't dense in $B$ (although it is colimit-dense). The problem is that the canonical diagram expressing an object in $B$ as a colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ can't express any relations, so its colimit is just the free abelian group on the elements of $B$. Glad I hesitated! It's exactly this kind of mess that inspired my MO question. I was trying to understand various notions of "generator" for this blog post: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/generators/

Comment: I *think* we can fix your counterexample by taking $A$ to be $\mathbb{Z}^2$, but continuing to keep $B$ as only the objects that can be presented as a single colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{Z}^2$ can express every allowable relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112791/discussion-between-parkey-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Answer (score 1):

Let me change notation. Let $X : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $Y : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ be functors, let $\mathcal{D}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ spanned by the images of $X : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $Y : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$, and let $\bar{X} = \varinjlim_\mathcal{I} h_X$ and $\bar{Y} = \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} h_Y$ in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$, where we define $h_T (S) = \mathcal{C} (S, T)$. Then,
$$\textstyle [\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}](\bar{X}, \bar{Y}) \cong \varprojlim_\mathcal{I} \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} \mathcal{C}(X, Y)$$
so a morphism $f : \bar{X} \to \bar{Y}$ can be decomposed into a family of morphisms $X (i) \to Y (j_i)$ indexed by $i \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{I}$, modulo a certain equivalence relation. On the other hand, even if $X$ and $Y$ have colimits in $\mathcal{C}$, at best we can only say
$$\textstyle \mathcal{C} \left( \varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X, \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y \right) \cong \varprojlim_\mathcal{I} \mathcal{C} \left( X, \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y \right)$$
and although there is a canonical comparison map
$$\textstyle \varprojlim_\mathcal{I} \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} \mathcal{C}(X, Y) \to \varprojlim_\mathcal{I} \mathcal{C} \left( X, \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y \right)$$
it is generally not a bijection.

*If* – this is a big if – the parallel pair $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X \rightrightarrows \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ you are interested in can be lifted through this comparison map, then their coequaliser is a colimit of a diagram constructed from $X$ and $Y$.

Indeed, let $f_0, f_1 : \bar{X} \to \bar{Y}$ be morphisms in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$. Then we may form their coequaliser $\bar{Z}$ in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$. There is a canonical diagram $R : \textbf{El} (\bar{Z}) \to \mathcal{D}$ whose colimit in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is $\bar{Z}$. Explicitly, $\textbf{El} (\bar{Z})$ is the following category:

- The objects in $\textbf{El} (\bar{Z})$ are pairs $(D, z)$ where $D$ is an object in $\mathcal{D}$ and $z$ is an element of $\bar{Z} (C)$.
- The morphisms $(D, z) \to (D', z')$ in $\mathcal{K}$ are the morphisms $g : D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ such that $z' \cdot g = z$.
- Composition is inherited from $\mathcal{D}$.

There is an obvious projection $R : \textbf{El} (\bar{Z}) \to \mathcal{D}$ and it is straightforward to check that $\bar{Z} \cong \varinjlim_{\textbf{El} (\bar{Z})} h_R$. I claim: $\varinjlim_{\textbf{El} (\bar{Z})} R$ is the coequaliser of $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X \rightrightarrows \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, in the strong sense that $\varinjlim_{\textbf{El} (\bar{Z})} R$ exists in $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if the coequaliser exists in $\mathcal{C}$ and they are isomorphic.

Let $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ spanned by the objects $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for every object $T$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the canonical map (induced by the restriction of the Yoneda embedding)
$$\mathcal{C} (C, T) \to [\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] (h_C, h_T)$$
is a bijection. The usual Yoneda lemma tells us $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \bar{\mathcal{D}}$, but, for any diagram $Z : \mathcal{K} \to \bar{\mathcal{D}}$,
$$\textstyle \varprojlim_\mathcal{K} \mathcal{C} \left( Z, T \right) \cong \varprojlim_\mathcal{K} [\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \left( h_Z, h_T \right) \cong [\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \left( \varinjlim_\mathcal{K} h_Z, h_T \right)$$
naturally in $T$, so if $\varinjlim_\mathcal{K} Z$ exists in $\mathcal{C}$ then it is also in $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$ – in short, $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$ is closed under colimits that exist in $\mathcal{C}$. In particular, $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X$ and $\varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y$ are in $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$, and if the parallel pair $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X \rightrightarrows \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ has a coequaliser than the coequaliser is also in $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$. Essentially, the definition of $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$ ensures that whatever can be proved about *iterated* colimits in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is also true in $\mathcal{C}$, so long as all the colimits involved can be realised in $\bar{\mathcal{D}}$. Thus, *if* the parallel pair $\varinjlim_\mathcal{I} X \rightrightarrows \varinjlim_\mathcal{J} Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ can be lifted to a parallel pair $\bar{X} \rightrightarrows \bar{Y}$ in $[\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$, then the coequaliser in $\mathcal{C}$ can be identified with the colimit in $\mathcal{C}$ of a diagram in $\mathcal{D}$.

It may be worth remarking that the Yoneda representation $\bar{\mathcal{D}} \to [\mathcal{D}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ may be neither fully faithful nor preserve colimits... but this is just rephrasing the warning in the first paragraph.